# How to use std::ratio for values larger than int64_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, long-integer

I want to encode solar mass as a std::ratio (in order to convert it to kg). 
How can I do such a thing if solar mass is 1.988478e+30 kg?

```cpp
std::ratio<(unsigned long long)1'988'478e+30, 1> kg_to_solar_mass // overflow
```

Comment: Why not just use `double`? You only know the solar mass up to 7 significant digits anyway.

Comment: ratio uses intmax_t as its templates

Comment: My point is, you don't need `std::ratio` if you just use `double`.

Comment: Thanks, but simple `double` is not strong typed. What I want is actually `std::ratio` for `double`s,

Answer (score 0):

A 64 bit unsigned integer (what the typical machine uses for a `unsigned long long`) has a max value of 18446744073709551615 (1.8446744073709551615e+19).  That is orders of magnitude smaller then a 1'988'478e+39 (or even [1.989e+30](https://www.google.com/search?q=solar%20mass&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS877US877&oq=solar%20mass&aqs=chrome..69i57j6j0l6.1608j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) and is going to overflow the integer.

You're either going to have to switch to a different type that uses doubles or some "Big Int" library, or not specify a ratio for a single kilogram to a solar mass.